# Vulnerability scanning vs fuzzing a web application

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, web-scanners, fuzzing

In the context of web applications, is vulnerability scanning a form of fuzzing?

I was told it wasn't the case, but here's what I know:

- Wikipedia defines fuzzing as "providing invalid, unexpected, or random data to the inputs of a computer program."
- Web application vulnerability scanners send invalid, unexpected data to identify vulnerabilities like SQL injections or cross site scripting.

Comment: Hint: read the description of the tags you used for the question...

Comment: you have the last two nouns in your first sentence backwards, and then the answer is "yes".

Comment: @dandavis "... a fuzzing of form"? ^^

Comment: heh; dan needs more coffee! it should say "_is fuzzing a form of vulnerability scanning_?" yes.

Comment: Sorry english is not my native language. My question was probably not well written. Simply put, in order to identify vulnerabilities, vulnerability scanners send various inputs like ', ' AND '1'='2, <script>alert<script>.
Can this be called fuzzing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of fuzzing is to send data to the interface with not much intelligence: garbage, random input and so on. When you are using a vulnerability scanner, you usually test for well known problems. In the case of web applications: injections and so on. It is possible that a vulnerability scanner can include some sort of fuzzing as one of the tests it performs.

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzing is a form of vulnerability testing. But vulnerability testing is not necessary a form of fuzzing. Some vulnerability scanners might use fuzzing techniques, modules or plugins to do so. For example Nessus has the following plugins to approach "unknown" issues in web applications ([source](https://www.scip.ch/?labs.20100312)):

- 44967: CGI Generic Command Execution Vulnerability (time based)
- 44136: CGI Generic Cookie Injection Scripting
- 44135: Web Server Generic Cookie Injection
- 44134: CGI Generic Unseen Parameters Discovery
- 43160: CGI Generic SQL Injection (blind, time based)
- 42872: CGI Generic Local File Inclusion Vulnerability (2nd pass)
- 42479: CGI Generic SQL Injection Vulnerability (2nd pass)
- 42427: CGI Generic SQL Injection Vulnerability (HTTP Headers)
- 42426: CGI Generic SQL Injection Vulnerability (HTTP Cookies)
- 42425: CGI Generic Persistent Cross-Site Scripting Vulnerability
- 42424: CGI Generic SQL Injection (blind)
- 42423: CGI Generic SSI Injection Vulnerability
- 42056: CGI Generic Local File Inclusion Vulnerability
- 42055: CGI Generic Format String Vulnerability
- 42054: CGI Generic SSI Injection Vulnerability
- 39469: CGI Generic Remote File Inclusion Vulnerability
- 39468: CGI Generic Header Injection Vulnerability
- 39467: CGI Generic Path Traversal Vulnerability
- 39465: CGI Generic Command Execution Vulnerability
- 11139: CGI Generic SQL Injection Vulnerability

This helps to determine issues which are not covered by other plugins based on derivative techniques, fingerprinting mechanism or channeled exploit approaches.